# Proximity to long weekends & holidays

Tags: r, datetime

**Data:**

I have a vector of dates in a tibble.

```
  # A tibble: 10 x 1
         Date
       <dttm>
 1 2017-04-04
 2 2017-04-05
 3 2017-04-07
 4 2017-04-10
 5 2017-04-11
 6 2017-04-12
 7 2017-04-13
 8 2017-04-14
 9 2017-04-17
10 2017-04-18
```

Reproducible using:

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(1491264000, 1491350400, 1491523200, 
1491782400, 1491868800, 1491955200, 1492041600, 1492128000, 1492387200, 
1492473600), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), .Names = "Date")
```

**Need**:

Two feature variables:

- 'Proximity to next holiday'
- 'Proximity to past holiday'

The intent is to determine if my response variable is dependent on if `Date` is close to a holiday or long weekend. For example, if 04-11 was a Holiday, I would want:

```
         Date   ProxNxtHol ProxPastHol
       <dttm>   
 1 2017-04-04   4          32
 2 2017-04-05   3          33
 3 2017-04-07   2          34
 4 2017-04-10   1          35
 5 2017-04-11   0          36
 6 2017-04-12   58         1
 7 2017-04-13   57         2
 8 2017-04-14   56         3
 9 2017-04-17   55         4
10 2017-04-18   54         5
```

While I can manually define all the holidays in a vector myself and calculate the difference between the two dates, this is cumbersome because the holidays vary by location globally. (I have a variable which can indicate location.)

Is there a predefined function which can indicate if a given date is a holiday or not, for a specified region?

Comment: Please provide the "vector of dates" and holidays you want to the Proximity variables to be created. What's even better is if you provide the desired output.

Comment: @useR Done. Question updated.

Comment: @ChiPak I've looked into `lubridate`. Doesn't look like it has the functionality I'm looking for. (Refer updated question).

Comment: Try `Holidays` package. It contains functions to interact with the TimeWarp database for trading holidays. For example you can do something like `holidays(2010:2017, allHolidays())`.

Comment: `library(timeDate)` has pre-defined function `isHoliday()` that determines if a date is a holiday or not. Example: `timeDate::isHoliday(timeDate("2017-12-31"), allHolidays())`

Answer (score 1):

I have come up with this `for` loop that computes both proximity as shown in your desired output. Please see the steps below.

Converting your structure to `data frame` and all its elements to class `Date`

```
> qdates <- data.frame(qdates)
> qdates$Date <- as.Date(qdates$Date)
> qdates

         Date
1  2017-04-04
2  2017-04-05
3  2017-04-07
4  2017-04-10
5  2017-04-11
6  2017-04-12
7  2017-04-13
8  2017-04-14
9  2017-04-17
10 2017-04-18
```

Using `library(timeDate)` to build a `data frame` of US holidays. You can add/modify your dates here or use other in-built functions that might contain federal holidays.

```
> library(timeDate)
> hdates <- data.frame(Dates = c(USNewYearsDay(2017), USInaugurationDay(2017), USMLKingsBirthday(2017), 
                                USLincolnsBirthday(2017), USWashingtonsBirthday(2017), USCPulaskisBirthday(2017), 
                                USGoodFriday(2017), USMemorialDay(2017), USIndependenceDay(2017), USLaborDay(2017), 
                                USColumbusDay(2017), USElectionDay(2017), USVeteransDay(2017), USThanksgivingDay(2017), 
                                USChristmasDay(2017)))

> colnames(hdates) <- "HolidayDate"
> hdates$HolidayDate <- as.Date(hdates$HolidayDate)
> hdates

   HolidayDate
1   2017-01-01
2   2017-01-20
3   2017-01-16
4   2017-02-12
5   2017-02-22
6   2017-03-06
7   2017-04-14
8   2017-05-29
9   2017-07-04
10  2017-09-04
11  2017-10-09
12  2017-11-07
13  2017-11-11
14  2017-11-23
15  2017-12-25
```

`for` loop to compute the date difference, and populate output.

```
for(i in 1:nrow(qdates)) {
  minDate <- max(hdates[which(hdates$HolidayDate <= qdates$Date[i]),])
  maxDate <- min(hdates[which(hdates$HolidayDate >= qdates$Date[i]),])

  qdates$ProxPastHol[i] <- abs(difftime(minDate, qdates$Date[i], units = "days"))
  qdates$ProxNxtHol[i] <- abs(difftime(maxDate, qdates$Date[i], units = "days"))
}

> qdates

         Date ProxPastHol ProxNxtHol
1  2017-04-04          29         10
2  2017-04-05          30          9
3  2017-04-07          32          7
4  2017-04-10          35          4
5  2017-04-11          36          3
6  2017-04-12          37          2
7  2017-04-13          38          1
8  2017-04-14           0          0
9  2017-04-17           3         42
10 2017-04-18           4         41
```

Hope this helps !!!